# How to read the text file and convert in 2-d array in clojure? Also, after converting want to modify it

Tags: clojure

I am just new to clojure and is wondering how to read a text file and then convert it to 2-d array, further want to do some modifications in it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

I have tried the following code, but don't know what to do further to do the modifications and printing the array

```clj
(ns test
  (:require [clojure.string :as str]))

(defn read-in-board [filepath]
  (str/split-lines (slurp filepath)))

(mapv vec (read-in-board "temp.txt"))
```

Comment: What input are you using, and what output are you expecting?

Comment: the text file consists of #(hash), -(dash) and @(at the rate) characters. Actually i want to read the text file consisting of these symbols and then find @ this character and want to save the path followed to reach this character.

Comment: Please provide a sample file, what you have tried and the output you are expecting. Right now it's hard to give any generic advice.

Comment: Ok. So lets say my text file has this data : 
%%%%%%*
***%%%%**
%%***%%**
**%%%%%
So i want to read it and store in 2-d array. And also want to do some modifications in this array, that is change  * to &. So that my output will have  %%%%%%&
&&&%%%%&&
%%&&&%%&&
&&%%%%%

Comment: If you just want to make it an array of lines (which would be a 2D array), you could just feed it into `clojure.string/split-lines`. That will split the string on newlines and give you a list of strings.